# NGINX DOCKER: change port 80

Tags: docker, nginx

My 80 port is busy because of pi-hole and I can't change pi hole-port.
I start nginx container with: `docker run -it -p 8080:8080`. With docker ps command the output is

```
3e7d6ea2fbb5   nginx 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp
```

and obviously mylocalip:8080 doesn't work. I try also with docker compose and set my docker compose like this:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
 web:
   image: nginx
   volumes:
    - ./templates:/etc/nginx/templates
   ports:
    - "5555:55"
   environment:
    - NGINX_HOST=foobar.com
    - NGINX_PORT=3333
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: What is wrong with using `-p 8080:80`?  Nginx should answer on your localhost 8080 port.

Comment: "5555:55" obviously isn't 8080. And neither is `NGINX_PORT=3333`. So, why did you expect either of those to work?

Comment: i copied this from web, i know it will not work but i tried

Answer (score 0):

This will stand up an nginx server on port 80 and map it to your local 8080 port, allowing you to access it on `localhost:8080` without re-configuring the default port:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80 nginx:latest
```

If you want to use docker compose, similarly you can do;

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: 'nginx:latest'
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

then

```
docker-compose up
```